# Do deleted utterances affect the LUIS utterance quota?

Tags: azure-language-understanding

I have an application in LUIS.  I get the message

> BadArgument: The number of examples per application version cannot exceed the limit 15000.

even though the application version has 0 utterances.  I have added utterances in the past and then deleted them because they did not meet my needs.  It looks like somehow LUIS holds these deleted utterances against me when calculating the limit.

Shouldn't I be able to add utterances since I currently have 0.  Is the utterance count happening incorrectly or this there something else that needs to be done to reset the count against me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no they don't.  In my case, I had a corrupted application version which I will have to take up with LUIS.

So one possible solution to the above error is that the version is corrupt and you should create a new version.  In my case, I programmatically populate a version through the API, so it was not such a big deal to return to a working state.